# Adding comments in django

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I am student and a beginner in Django. I just want to ask how I can convert this comment code from function view to class view. Also note that the book has a slug field.

```
def BookDetail(request, id):
most_recent = Book.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
book= get_object_or_404(Book, id=id)
form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
if request.method == "POST":
    if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.user = request.user
        form.instance.post = book
        form.save()
        return redirect(reverse("book-detail", kwargs={
            'id': book.pk
        }))
context = {
    'form': form,
    'book': book,
    'most_recent': most_recent,

}
return render(request, 'catalog/book_detail.html', context)
```

from the above code to the one below:

```
class BookDetailView(DetailView):
model = Book
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define detail view and `get_context_data` where you can add as many fields which can pass it a template.

```
class BookDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Book

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # adding additional field like below
        context['now'] = timezone.now()
        return context
```

Comment: um what do you mean adding additional fields? i have forms.py  sorry for late reply.

Comment: I have added now in context on above code similar you can add as many additional fields to context which can be used in template